# Fields_for disappear when adding accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes, fields-for

I'm doing a nested form in Rails 3.2.5, but when I add the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` my `fields_for` disappear (they just stop showing in my form).
This are my models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :variants_attributes

    has_many :variants
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants

    validates :title, presence: true
end
```

My second model is

```
class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    attr_accessible :price, :sku, :weight, :inventory_quantity, :product_id
end
```

And in my view I have

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @product], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

 <%= render 'admin/shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

 <fieldset>
  <legend>Producto Nuevo</legend>  
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :title, 'Título', class: 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
   </div>

    **<%= f.fields_for :variants do |variant| %>
     <%= render 'inventory_fields', f: variant %>
    <% end %>**  

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_inventory_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :inventory_quantity, 'How many are in stock?', class: 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :inventory_quantity, class: 'span1', value: '1' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The part between the ** is the one that is not being printed. And when I remove accepts_nested_attributes_for in my Product model fields_for start showing again but my form won't work.
What's happening?!?!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the controller new action call

```
@product.varients.build
```

That should create 1 in memory varient in the product varient collection and it should bind to the fields for

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't know that fields_for needed an existing attribute in order to render the fields.

Comment: If it was an `has_one` association you'd need to call `@product.build_varient`. It took a while to me to find it out. See [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one) for more info.