# Unpermitted parameters error for permitted attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a [rails app](https://github.com/OneAcreCafe/volunteers) for doing [volunteer scheduling](http://vols.herokuapp.com). Shifts have multiple workers. I am trying to pass the worker ids from the [edit form](https://github.com/OneAcreCafe/volunteers/blob/master/app/views/shifts/_form.html.haml) to the [shifts controller](https://github.com/OneAcreCafe/volunteers/blob/master/app/controllers/shifts_controller.rb).

The input form is being generated with the appropriate elements:

```
<select id="shift_workers" multiple="multiple" name="shift[workers][]">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">username</option>
</select>
```

In the controller I have the following code:

```
def shift_params
  params.require(:shift).permit(:start, :end, :size, :task_id, workers: [])
end
```

Despite this I am getting the following error when editing shifts:

```
Unpermitted parameters: workers
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
workers_ids: []
```

Rather than this:

```
workers: []
```

because the database stores an array of the worker ids, not an array of workers.

Have a look [here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values)